# Custom ItemsControl Child Control Namespace Issue

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm having trouble adding controls with x:name to my custom control.

Adding the x:name="startDate" causes everything to break. Otherwise this works perfectly.

I have a custom control inheriting from ItemsControl.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ControlCSI
{
    public partial class SlideMenu : ItemsControl
    {
        public SlideMenu()
        {
            // Required to initialize variables
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the markup definition of that class

```
<ItemsControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="ControlCSI.SlideMenu"
d:DesignWidth="200" d:DesignHeight="800">

<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

<ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
            <Border Height="auto" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="5" >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="23" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Background="Transparent">
                        <Image Source="/ControlCSI;component/Images/GlossyBlack/bg_pulltab.png"  />
                    </Border>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" >
                        <Border CornerRadius="10,0,0,10" BorderBrush="#11c2f1" BorderThickness="0">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <ImageBrush  ImageSource="/ControlCSI;component/Images/GlossyBlack/bg_nav.png"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Template>
```

and here is the implementation:

```
<ControlCSI:SlideMenu x:Name="SlideOutMenu" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
            <ControlCSI:SlideMenu.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform TranslateX="180"/>
            </ControlCSI:SlideMenu.RenderTransform>

            <telerik:RadButton Margin="5,10,5,0"  Click="RadButton_Click" Tag="30" Content="30 Days" Style="{StaticResource SliderButton}"  />
            <telerik:RadButton  Click="RadButton_Click" Tag="60" Content="60 Days" Style="{StaticResource SliderButton}"/>
            <telerik:RadButton  Click="RadButton_Click" Tag="90" Content="3 Months" Style="{StaticResource SliderButton}"/>
            <telerik:RadButton  Click="RadButton_Click" Tag="180" Content="6 Months" Style="{StaticResource SliderButton}"/>
            <telerik:RadDatePicker x:Name="startDate" x:Uid="startDate"  DropDownOpened="startDate_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="startDate_DropDownClosed"    DateTimeWatermarkContent="Start Date" Style="{StaticResource SliderDatePicker}"  Template="{StaticResource RadDateTimePickerControlTemplate1}"  />
            <telerik:RadDatePicker  DropDownOpened="startDate_DropDownOpened" DropDownClosed="startDate_DropDownClosed"    DateTimeWatermarkContent="End Date" Style="{StaticResource SliderDatePicker}" Template="{StaticResource RadDateTimePickerControlTemplate1}"  />


        </ControlCSI:SlideMenu>
```

errors:

```
  A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ControlCSI
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'ErrorResources' property not found on 'ControlCSI.ResourceWrapper' 'ControlCSI.ResourceWrapper' (HashCode=42863040). BindingExpression: Path='ErrorResources.ErrorWindowTitle' DataItem='ControlCSI.ResourceWrapper' (HashCode=42863040); target element is 'ControlCSI.ErrorWindow' (Name=''); target property is 'Title' (type 'System.Object')..
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'ErrorResources' property not found on 'ControlCSI.ResourceWrapper' 'ControlCSI.ResourceWrapper' (HashCode=42863040). BindingExpression: Path='ErrorResources.ErrorWindowGenericError' DataItem='ControlCSI.ResourceWrapper' (HashCode=42863040); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='IntroductoryText'); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..
System.Windows.Data Error: BindingExpression path error: 'ErrorResources' property not found on 'ControlCSI.ResourceWrapper' 'ControlCSI.ResourceWrapper' (HashCode=42863040). BindingExpression: Path='ErrorResources.ErrorWindowErrorDetails' DataItem='ControlCSI.ResourceWrapper' (HashCode=42863040); target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='LabelText'); target property is 'Text' (type 'System.String')..
```

x:name creates a local variable so i am guessing that this is a namespace issue ?

Comment: I recoded the custom control to be a UserControl with a ContentPresenter and everything worked right up to the moment I add x:name to a control.

Comment: I receive the exact same set of errors.

Comment: Remove `x:Uid` it does nothing.  What happens if you remove the assignment to the `Template` property and use the default template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I switched to a UserControl (which after some documentation review was the right way to go).

I added the buttons and date pickers inside of the control and and exposed them by binding to dependency properties.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can add x:Name to that control because it already provides a Name property. Check out the remarks section of [this msdn link].[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189028%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

You can however use that Name property in the same way you could use x:Name (I think).

Best of luck

Adding link cause I'm not sure I used the linking behavior right :P
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189028%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: its funny that you suggested this.... i literally just got done looking at that and it produced the same error =\

Comment: Bummer :(  I hope you can get this figured out

Comment: x:Name is specially handled.  If the control on which it is defined has a `Name` property the value of `x:Name` will be assigned to it.  In fact when `Name` property is available on the element there is nothing to distinguish between the use of `Name` or `x:Name` at all.  `x:Name` allows names to be attached to elements even though they don't have a `Name` property so that functions such as `FindName` still work.  For this reason `x:Name` is prefered over just using `Name`.